# Game theory - Strategic Games - Incomplete Information problem

Tags: game-theory

Player $A$ and Player $B$ contribute hours towards building a house. If player $A$ contributes $x ≥ 0$ hours and player $B$ contributes $y ≥ 0$ hours, then the value of the house will be  $x + y + \frac{xy}{2}$.
The contribution of each player comes at a cost:

- Contributing $x$ hours costs player $A$: $\frac{x^2}{2}$.
- Contributing $y$ hours costs player $B$: $ay^2$, where $ a = \frac{1}{2}$ or $a = 1$.

Player $B$ knows the value of $a$, but player $A$ does not:

Player $A$ believes that $a = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}\text{ with probability } p\\1\text{ with probability } 1-p\end{cases}$.

(i) What is the maximisation problem that player B needs to solve to optimise their
own effort? Show also that

$$y_{opt} = \frac{2 + x}{4a} .$$

(ii) Find the Bayes-Nash equilibrium as a function of $p$ for $x$ and $y$ at the two cost
values.

I'm not sure how to solve this. What I have so far is:

Player A's strategy is $(x)$ hours.

Player B's strategy is $(y)$ hours.

There are 2 types. B either chooses $ a = \frac{1}{2}$ or $a = 1$.

If $ a = \frac{1}{2}$ then the payoff will be

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 & \text{y}\\
\hline
x & p (x + y + \frac{xy}{2})
\end{array}
$$

If $ a = 1$ then the payoff will be

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 & \text{y}\\
\hline
x & (1-p) (x + y + \frac{xy}{2})
\end{array}
$$

Comment: So can you write down A's expected payoff? Given, that, what is the optimal choice of x for A?

Comment: The expected payoff for A would be (++/2) + (1−)(++/2)